# How do you reply to email thread with google Mailapp?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm using google Mailapp Api to send out email automatically from spreadsheet.

I wrote a script to automatically sendout email with spreadsheet data.
For now, my script sends out a new email.

Is there a way to send out (reply) email to existing email thread with google Mailapp api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [reply() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#reply(String)) of the GmailApp service to reply to any specific thread.

```
 var thread = GmailApp.getThreadById(id);
 thread.reply("Thank you!");
```