# Need Script Code for Automating Emails Based on Cell Input in Google Sheets

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I am trying to create a script that will auto-email a person. Basically, this sheet is going to have a list of items and track those items, and I need to assign each item when it comes it. When I assign it to a person's name, I want the script to then email that person. There are only about 15 people, but I assume I would need a script for each person aka if I put "Sally" in the sheet, there is a script to now email "Sally" to say she has been added to this task.
Ideally, I would like a way to also generate an email again to "Sally" if I update her task, add a comment to it, or do another input to do some sort of follow-up.

Any help would be appreciated immensely!

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for free resources and more details.

Answer (score 3):

It wont be good to directly post the complete solution but I will mention the required functionalities which I get in my mind , please use them to solve your task:

1. onEdit(e) - use this to trigger a particular set of functions whenever a particular range or cell value is changed(it may be automated or manual both can trigger this function) look into the official documentation for how to detect the changes occurred in which cell(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
2. once the new task is assigned to a person(for first time) send an email to that person using GmailApp(install the library in app script) , get the ThreadById of this email and store it into the sheet along the same row, if any changes are made afterwords like adding comments or something,use this threadId to reply to the same email using "thread.reply"([How do you reply to email thread with google Mailapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567672/how-do-you-reply-to-email-thread-with-google-mailapp))
3. I think you have also asked how to make the system dynamic, I mean you are right now coding as if each member needs a code for his/her entry. Please study a bit deeper you will easily find an approach to make it dynamic using the onEdit and some for loops as the way you are thinking is not recommended in automation scenarios.

Comment: If possible, share a spreadsheet that exactly demonstrates your need! We are waiting!

Comment: hi @Sidney Cardoso dos Santos
, I have posted the possible method that can be used, I don't know about the complete requirement(which seems to be very big - similar to Jira software) , we can surely help with the possible ways; thank you